# Performance Difference Between a 3D program and a 2D program

Tags: java, performance

I have written a program which places solar panels on 3D buildings, but as a shortcut, when placing panels for each face I treated it as a plane and therefore it became a 2D problem.

My question is this:
I am able to measure the performance of my program in terms of time taken but is there a way to quantify the time saved by transforming it into a 2D problem rather than carrying out the calculations just in 3D?

Of course an exact figure can not be obtained unless I rewrite the program and do the calculations just in 3D for a performance comparison, but does anyone have references or knowledge of how much improvement (if any) may have been made by working in one dimension less?

Any suggestions/tips/discussions would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, that depends on the algorithms you're using. Have a look at the Big O notation on how to determine the rough performance characteristics of an algorithm.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I haven't come across the Big O Notation before. I just checked out a beginner's guide and for my algorithm, I analyse each face, for each building. I guess this nesting would make it a O(N^2). However, it still doesn't quite answer the question of the difference in performance between carrying out calculations in 3D and 2D

Comment: Well, as I said, it depends on the algorithms. If you just save a few calculations the performance difference is probably quite small, if you can leave out loops or other bigger parts due to the missing dimension the difference might be bigger. If the algorithms have the same `O(x)` performance you'd have to test in order to get a more exact difference. There's no general 2D vs. 3D performance comparison.

Comment: Placing solar panels on the surface(s) of a 3D building remains a 2D problem in computational terms.  If you don't believe me take a cardboard model of a building and cut it along all the edges where 2 walls meet (or where a wall meets a roof).  Now flatten it all out.  Hey presto, two dimensions !